# Binding to a property value from two different class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF application, I've two classes, ClassA and ClassB. I have already set the DataContext to ClassA in codebehind

```
this.DataContext = new ClassA();
```

So in my XAML I can bind a label content to property `Wish` of ClassA like below

```
<Label Name="myLabel" FontSize="40" Content="{Binding Wish}"/>
```

And this works perfectly fine. But the problem comes when I am trying the same with another class, ClassB. With my `this.DataContext = new ClassA();` still staying in the code behind, I am trying to get a property value from ClassB (and yes, ClassB has a property with same name and code) doing like below in my XAML

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ClassB}">
            <Label Name="myLabelFromB" FontSize="40" Content="{Binding Wish}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

in which I'm failing. When I run, the MainWindow just displays the first label only.
Why `myLabelFromB` doesnt get the value of `ClassB.Wish` even when its parent's DataContext is set to ClassB? Is it possible to achieve the same without modifying my existing code behind?

Comment: `ClassB` property exist in `ClassA`? Show code for ClassA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that to work, you need to have `ClassB property in ClassA` somewhat like this:

```
public class ClassA
{
   public ClassA()
   {
      this.ClassB = new ClassB();
   }

   public string Wish { get; set;}
   public ClassB ClassB { get; set;}
}
```

Then this will work too :

```
<StackPanel>
   <Label Name="myLabelFromB" FontSize="40" Content="{Binding ClassB.Wish}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer @Rohit. But my doubt is why cant i get the Wish property even if myLabelFromB is using the DataContext as ClassB? Is it because I never created an instance of ClassB?

Comment: Yeah you have to create an instance of ClassB to bind to it. Either it in resource section or like i mentioned in my answer.